# How to check if a property of a list is null using a proper approach?

Tags: java, spring, list, stream, java-stream

I have the following method in my Java app:

```
private void save(final CopyRequest request) {

    if (request.getName() != null) {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

I update this method by converting the method parameters to `List<CopyRequest>` as shown below:

```
private void save(final List<CopyRequest> requestList) {

    if (requestList.getName() != null) {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

So, should I check if the name property is null via `requestList.stream().forEach(request -> request.getName == null)` or something like that?

Comment: Do you want to do "stuff" only when all `CopyRequest` instances in the list have a non-null `name`, or do you want to do "stuff" for each instance that doesn't have a `name`?

Comment: What is `reqeustList.getName()`? THere is no such method unless you're using yoru own `List`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Stream#allMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-).

```
if(requestList != null 
    && requestList.stream().allMatch(request -> request != null 
            && request.getName() != null)){

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the approach depends on what actually you want to perform.

First option is - save the list if and only if every item has a name (all or nothing).

```
  boolean allWithName = requestList.stream()
      .map(CopyRequest::getName)
      .allMatch(Objects::nonNull);
  if(allWithName){
    // do stuff
  }
```

Second option - save every item having a name (selective save)

```
   requestList.stream()
      .filter(request -> request.getName() != null) // (1)
      .forEach(this::save); // Note: it is overloaded version for single request
```

In fact, you can even omit filtering with `(1)` because overloaded version already performs the check

Answer (score 1):

Slight variation using *filter* for null check,

```
if(requestList != null 
    && requestList.stream()
       .filter(Objects:nonNull)
       .allMatch(request -> request.getName() != null)) {
   // code here
}
```